# iterate through a dictionary inside a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

So let's say i have

```
dictionary = {
    'Moe': {
             'name':'moe',
             'age':24,
             'married':False
           },
    'Jon': {
             'name':'jon',
             'age':22,
             'married':False
           },
    'andrew': 
           {'name':'andrew',
            'age':27,
            'married':True
           }
}
```

Suppose that i want to iterate through the dictionary to find out how many person is married in this dictionary, how can i do it?

Comment: `dict.values()` returns an iterable of the values. In your case it will be an iterable of those dicts. To get the value of a key you use the `dictionary[key]` syntax. In Python `bool` is a subclass of `int` where `True == 1` and `False == 0`. `sum(iterable)` returns the sum of the values of an iterable. Try to put these together to get an expression to achieve what you want.

Comment: `sum(person["married"] for person in dictionary.values())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
result = 0
for x in dictionary:
    if dictionary[x]['married'] == True:
        result += 1
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following generator comprehension to lookup `married` in the inner dictionaries setting the default value to `0`, and take the `sum`:

```
sum(i.get('married', 0) for i in dictionary.values())
#1
```

Comment: `dictionary.values()` could be better

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
count = 0
for v in dictionary.values():
  if v['married']:
    count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is like this:

```
n_married = 0 
for key, item in d.items(): 
    name, age, married = item 
    n_married += 1 if married else 0 
print(n_married)
```